# In Excel, how can I use a function to split an unknown number of terms into different cells on a separate sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

K2 of Sheet1 contains this:  `Girl Scouts; camping; camp grounds; children`

I need Sheet2 to take that information and put each term between the semi-colons into their own cells.  The catch is:  There will always be an unknown amount of terms.  Sometimes there's 1, sometimes there's 8.  I can't do this with the Text to Columns feature, because I need it to be more automated as I have thousands of rows with this in K2.

For context:
Sheet1 has several columns with information that people have entered including title, creator, description, size, subjects, etc.  This was all entered with the idea of creating IPTC metadata for a large collection of images.  HOWEVER, we've also decided we want the DublinCore metadata, too.  Which means I need to translate things like subjects that are separated by semicolons into several cells under the column of "subject."  That way I can use it as a csv to import into an XML document.

Here's sample of the original sheet:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5dF4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.

Probably the most effective would be a macro that would parse the text with just a single button push, or with an event trigger (eg worksheet_activate so when you go to sheet 1, the sheet gets populated.

For formulas, assuming that you will have a maximum of 10 entries:

If you have Excel 2013+ with the `FILTERXML` function, you can use:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!$K2,";","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s["&COLUMNS($A:A)&"]")),"")
```

and fill right for the ten cells.  Then fill down as far as needed.

If you have an earlier version of Excel, you can use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!$K2,";",REPT(" ",99)),{1;99;198;297;396;495;594;693;792;891;990;1089},99)),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")
```

Comment: Where would I use this formula?  Say I have 10 cells, do I change it for each cell?  What portion of the formula causes it to select the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. word?

Comment: @ArchivistG To answer your questions:  1.  On sheet 2 where you want to see the results. 2. No 3. `Columns($A:A)`

Comment: For some reason, I when I put all 10 cells in there (i.e. ($D2:M2)), nothing shows up.  However, if change it to ($D2:G2) I get one of the terms in D2, if I change it to ($D2:F2) I get a different term in D2, etc.

Comment: @ArchivistG Put ten cells in where?  Not in the formula, I hope.

Comment: Is the ($A:A) telling it where to put the extracted terms?

Comment: @ArchivistG   No.  Enter the formula **as I posted it** in some cell on the worksheet where you want to see the results.  Then, as I wrote, **fill right**.  That means to select the cell.  At the lower right corner there is a dark square. If you hover the cursor over that square it will change to a cross. Left click and "drag" the cursor to the right ten cells. The formula should fill the cells, changing the references as you go.  Then you can select the entire row, and **fill down** as far as needed. This all assumes you provided proper sheet and cell references in your question.

Comment: @ArchivistG Actually `Columns($A:A)` is instructing which of the extracted substrings to output.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Have yo tried to just save the file as a csv or text file, open it up again and select the colon as a separator?  Is there any data in the rows beneath the section you've posted?

If it is just one row you want separated, a quick a dirty method may be to colon separate the spreadhsheet and save to a new file, open the old file and paste it back in in the place of the existing row.

If you still need to separate the other rows but with a different separator, you could go through the process again for the remaining rows, then paste each collection of rows back together.

It would be helpful if you posted a sample of the layout in the lower rows - are they all similarly formatted? Because there may be a quicker way to accomplish what you want but without knowing the layout of the existing sheet it's hard to give a firm answer.

Comment: So, each row has a lot of information.  This is just one cell in that row that I need to translate into separated cells somewhere SO that I can have them all tab delimited.

Comment: So are you just wanting the existing cell with the semi colons separated into multiple new cells in new columns?

If so then copying the entire column to a new sheets, opening it as a csv with a colon delimiter to split it across multiple columns, then adding enough columns to the original sheet to accommodate & pasting should work.

Comment: Any reason `Text to Columns` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Will - yes.  I need it to go into however many columns it takes.  I'll have 10 cells set aside, just in case, but I just need however many there are to go into as many cells as it takes to hold them.

Comment: cybernetic.nomad, There are so many rows from different collections (thousands and thousands) that I'm not sure that would cut it.  I'm trying to make it so that I can just paste in the work they've put in, and have the neighboring page translate it all in one fell swoop.